# Leaflet VectorGrid interactivity doesn't work if Leaflet.markercluster is used

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to use Leaflet VectorGrid [interactivity](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html#interactivity) option for click and mouse events:

```
const vectorGrid = L.vectorGrid.slicer(geoJsonDocument, {
    rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
    vectorTileLayerStyles: {
      sliced: geoJSONStyle(false)
    },
    maxZoom: 22,
    indexMaxZoom: 5, // max zoom in the initial tile index
    interactive: true
  });

  vectorGrid.on("mouseover", function (e) {
    console.log("mouseover");
  });

  vectorGrid.on("click", function (e) {
    console.log("click");
  });
```

However, interactivity doesn't work if `Leaflet.markercluster` is used.

I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-darwin-m4pxr?file=/src/index.js).

If you comment `map.addLayer(mcg);`, interactivity works.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/393553/115

Comment: I'm gonna say that the example is not minimal (as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ) - there's CORS, Heroku, and React involved. I suggest trying to reproduce without any of those.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I created [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-darwin-m4pxr?file=/src/index.js) without any React or API and updated my question.

Comment: You're suffering from https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4135 - setting `preferCanvas` to `false` works around the issue. The problem is not vectorgrid vs markercluster interactions, but rather vector features in a `L.Canvas` (markercluster polygons) vs anything other interactive layers (vectorgrid tiles).

Comment: @IvanSanchez thank you for your prompt response. Maybe you can post answer here and [gis so](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/393553/115) and we can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from Leaflet contributor:

> You're suffering from github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4135 - setting
> preferCanvas to false works around the issue. The problem is not
> vectorgrid vs markercluster interactions, but rather vector features
> in a L.Canvas (markercluster polygons) vs anything other interactive
> layers (vectorgrid tiles